# Android get all available storage devices

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Is there any function/method which allow to detect all kind of different storage to your phone with their names. I mean to detect all internal/external storage if there is more than one available on your device. And how to detect if there is available SD Card or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see below, may be help you.<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450650/how-to-list-additional-external-storage-folders-mount-points/15131810#15131810

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about other types of storage device, I only know Internal Storage and External Storage device for android.

Now for check available **external storage** something like,

```
public static boolean isSdPresent() {

return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

}

return type boolean(true->available,false->NA).
```

And for **Internal storage**, (Internal storage is always remain (present) so no need to check it) just get like,

```
File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
```

Now, in both case to check available free memory and usage memory,

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
return Formatter.formatFileSize(this, availableBlocks * blockSize);
```

Comment: `getBlockSize()` is deprecated, You may directly use `path.getFreeSpace()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
public static boolean isSdCardPresent() {

        return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

        }
```