# Android - get all available storage up to Android 5.0

Tags: android, memory

is there any way how to get available storage on any Android phone from various brands up to Android 5.0? On Sony and Samsung, both have different approach to show memory, Environment.getExternalStorage() is not useful...

I want to give user an option to choose, where to save downloaded data.

Any help in this?

Thx

Comment: See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645189/android-get-list-of-all-available-storage

Comment: Yea, but Android 5.0 changed things a lot, I have problem especially with Sony Xperia's and their implementation of available memory.

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalMediaDirs()