# Checking if File Exisits using /mnt/sdcard

Tags: android

I have like many people used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() to work out where the SDCard is located on the phone. I have through bought a Galaxy S3 and hit a issue with this phone.

The Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() does not go to the correct place. (See this [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)) for more info.

I have used the method (hashset one) to work out the path to the external sdcard but when I use it, it does not work

```
HashSet<String> testing = getExternalMounts();

Iterator it = testing.iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
        {

            String value = (String)it.next();
            File file = new File(value, DB_EXPORTED_NAME);

            if(file.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(context, "File exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
}
```

It always comes up as Not Found. Can someone let me know where I am going wrong

thanks for your time

Comment: Print `file.getAbsolutePath()` and make sure the path you are looking for is what you think it is.

Comment: For the Emulator "Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "File : " + file);" is shown as "File : /mnt/sdcard/Database". This is what I was expecting and I know the file is there but will not find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This is me trying to code at 11pm. The file is inside a Directory that I have not added into the string. Add it in and works perfect.

```
File file = new File(value, SAVED_DIR + "\" + DB_EXPORTED_NAME);
```

Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Try the .getAbsolutePath() function instead of .toString()