# Android Access External Storage

Tags: android, storage

I am facing some storage issue. i am working on an application where i have to access phone's on board external storage and an External sdCard storage which i am getting with this code

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

But when onBoard external memory exists then this code returns the path of onBoard memory not the external sdCard while the sdCard is mounted

now the problem is..
i want to access both memories onBoard and external sdcard is there any way to access both memories

Comment: Please select an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
String m_str = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               .getAbsolutePath().toString();           //return path sdcard/mnt
```

Comment: This will return the path of build-in storage in my phone. Not the SD card inserted.