# Can't check if file on sdcard exists

Tags: android, file

I'm trying to make a simple check if the file exist. I saw similar questions here, but they didn't help. When I run my application, the app crashes and I got message "Unfortunatelly, fileCheck1 has stopped". I got this error both on emulator and smartphone.

My code:

```
package com.example.fileCheck1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    TextView msgText;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        msgText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/ping.xml";
        File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(Path);
        if(file.exists()){
            msgText.setText("Found");
        }
        if(!file.exists()){
            msgText.setText("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

In my Manifest such permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that problem is here:

```
getBaseContext()
```

where it is assigned to **`NULL`**. You really don't need this line. You can simply achieve your goal with

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/ping.xml";
File f = new File(path);
if (f.exists()) {
   // do your stuff
}
else {
  // do your stuff
}
```

### Update:

If you or someone else have Samsung Galaxy S3, please follow @Raghunandan's answer because in this case `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns internal memory.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I figured out that the problem was there, but i didn't know why.

Answer (score 3):

I have samsung galaxy s3 with android 4.1.2. My internal phone memory is named sdcard0 and my external card extSdCard.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

So the above returns the path of sdcard0  which is internal phone memory

So get the actual path you can use the below

```
String externalpath = new String();
String internalpath = new String();

public  void getExternalMounts() {
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try
{
Process proc = runtime.exec("mount");
InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
String line;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("secure")) continue;
    if (line.contains("asec")) continue;

    if (line.contains("fat")) {//external card
        String columns[] = line.split(" ");
        if (columns != null && columns.length > 1) {
            externalpath = externalpath.concat("*" + columns[1] + "\n");
        }
} 
        else if (line.contains("fuse")) {//internal storage
        String columns[] = line.split(" ");
        if (columns != null && columns.length > 1) {
            internalpath = internalpath.concat(columns[1] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  System.out.println("Path  of sd card external............"+externalpath);
  System.out.println("Path  of internal memory............"+internalpath);
}
```

Once you get the path

```
    File file = new File(internalpath+"/ping.xml");// internalpath or external path
    if(file.exists()){
        msgText.setText("Found");
    }
    else{
        msgText.setText("Not Found");
    }
```

**UPDATE :**

The above solution is not recommended. May not work well. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will always return the path of External Storage. In most cases it is a Sdcard.

From the docs

> public static File getExternalStorageDirectory ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Return the primary external storage directory.
>   This directory may not currently be accessible if it has been mounted
>   by the user on their computer, has been removed from the device, or
>   some other problem has happened. You can determine its current state
>   with getExternalStorageState().
>
> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
emmm, shouldn't it always return external storage path? Any way this was not a problem, and it correctly return path on my Sony and emulatator. The problem was in crashing. Anyway thank you

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returned the path of sdcard0 which was actually phone memory in my case. In such cases you can get the actual path using the above code.

Comment: nice. i did not know about galaxy s3 issue. good to know. i will update asnwer(still dont know who and why downvoted me, interesting)

Comment: @ Sajmon have a look at the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0

Comment: No, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() **always** returns the path of the **External Storage**.  The problem is that **you don't actually want** the "External Storage" (which indeed, today is often implemented with space borrowed as needed from internal flash chips) but rather a vendor-optional SD card slot.  And this is not the API to find that on a phone where that is not the primary "External Storage"

Comment: @ChrisStratton agreed. I gotta know about this after having a chat with commonsware and checking the docs. Gonna edit it

Comment: @Raghunandan, I am facing issue with Android 6.0 it returns internal storage path with Environment.getExter‌​nalStorageDirectory() but I want external storage and I want to write file on it. Can you please help me in this? I tried all solution and feeling helpless now.

Comment: @Anvesh this answer is old.lot of changes have happened since the day I answered. Try posting a new question

Comment: @Anvesh do look at Adopting Storage devices @ https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ping.xml");
    if(file.exists()){
        msgText.setText("Found");
    }
    else{
        msgText.setText("Not Found");
    }
```

Comment: Not necessory to explain code.. That is not a big deal... Do not understand.. Just one line...