# External Storage issue in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am using the path as `"/mnt/sdcard/myfolder/myfile"` to store my file in android app. Will it give any error when the app running on the phone which does not have any sdcard slot(phone like Nexus S)?

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15744282/1381827

Comment: Use the location from /sdcard/myfolder/myfile, /mnt is not necessary. To check the availability of sdcard you can use, android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't use a hardcoded path to access external storage. If you are not already, you should be using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

Answer (score 3):

You have to check whether external storage is available or not

```
private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](http://niravranpara.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-internal-and-external-storage.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) :

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```