# Why there are two folders sdcard and sdcard2 under /mnt on my android device

Tags: android

When using Eclipse file explorer to navigate my android directories, I saw `mnt/sdcard` and `mnt/sdcard2`, see below image:

When calling`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` it returns `mnt/sdcard`, so I think the `mnt/sdcad` is the `external storage` , and `mnt/sdcard2` is my actual SD card, is that true? And how can I use code to access files under `mnt/sdcard2` ?

[image]

P.S.

It seems that I can access the external sd card directly:

```
    File extStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String parent = extStorageDir.getParent();
    File extSdCardDir = new File(parent+"/sdcard2");

    File file = new File(extSdCardDir, "DemoFile.jpg");
```

But I wonder the extra sd card will change name in other cases.

Comment: i had the same problem in samsung galaxy s3 one is sdcard0 which is the external storage on phone and extSdCard which is the external sd card. this `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the one external storage on your phone. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: @Raghunandan so no way to access the external sd card?

Comment: check this  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory() for more info

Comment: Quoting form docs In devices with multiple "external" storage directories (such as both secure app storage and mountable shared storage), this directory represents the "primary" external storage that the user will interact with. here's a similar answer by commons ware http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215466/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-getabsolutepath-gives-a-different-pa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `getExternalStorage` will return your built-in external storage. Unfortunately, as of Jelly Bean applications are no longer able to utilize the SD card if the device also has built-in storage as well as an SD card. You can try working around it through shell commands or hardcoding paths, but without root there is no reliable way to access it anymore.

This was just recently added the Android CTS, which all OEMs must comply with in order to use the Play store.

[Compatibility Program Overview | Android Developers](http://source.android.com/compatibility/overview.html)

[Section 9.5 (pg. 34) of Android 4.3 Compatibility Definition](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/android-4.3-cdd.pdf)

> Device implementations that include multiple external storage paths
>   MUST NOT allow Android applications to write to the secondary external
>   storage.

[Storage Options | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

> It's possible that a device using a partition of the internal storage
>   for the external storage may also offer an SD card slot. In this case,
>   the SD card is not part of the external storage and your app cannot
>   access it (the extra storage is intended only for user-provided media
>   that the system scans).

[Android 4.2 APIs | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html)

> **Saving data in a multi-user environment**
>
> Whenever your app saves user preferences, creates a database, or
>   writes a file to the user’s internal or external storage space, that
>   data is accessible only while running as that user.
>
> To be certain that your app behaves properly in a multi-user
>   environment, do not refer to your internal app directory or external
>   storage location using hard-coded paths and instead always use the
>   appropriate APIs:
>
> ```
> For access to internal storage, use getFilesDir(), getCacheDir(), or openFileOutput().
> For access to external storage, use getExternalFilesDir() or getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().
> ```
>
> No matter which of these APIs you use to save data for a given user,
>   the data will not be accessible while running as a different user.
>   From your app’s point of view, each user is running on a completely
>   separate device.

Comment: Is that true? I installed one file explorer app on my device and it correctly listed the files under the external sd card.

Comment: I'm afraid so. Not a very big fan of it personally, but I'm sure Google has their reasons for it.

Comment: It seems that I can access the external sd card directly.

Comment: That isn't recommended as they have already made clear their intentions to break apps ability to do so. That also isn't very reliable across different OEMs since some htc devices use `/sdext` as well as `/sdcard`.