# Unable to load image in a ImageView from the Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-imageview, android-bitmap, internal-storage

I am trying to add the Image from the the Internal Memory.

I am trying to use this code for that

```
        ImageView message_image=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_image);
        File imgFile = new File(img_db);
        Log.e("img_db",img_db+"------------->");
        if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            message_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
         }
```

here img_db is my path that i am getting from my Sqlite table.when i log it i get the fath like this

> E/img_db: file:///storage/sdcard0/download/img11024FILE.jpg------------->

I have already given this permission in my manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For downloading image and save to the phone i am using this code

```
  public String downloadFile(String url_i_) {

    try {


        URL url
                = new URL(url_i_);
        Log.e("url_fetch--->img", String.valueOf(url));

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        // connect
        urlConnection.connect();

        // set the path where we want to save the file
        SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // create a new file, to save the downloaded file
        rand = new External_function().getnRandom();
        file = new File(SDCardRoot, "/download/img" + rand+".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        // this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
        totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();



        // create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            // update the progressbar //


                    float per = ((float) downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100;
                    /*cur_val.setText("Downloading.... " + downloadedSize
                            + "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int) per
                            + "%)");*/
                    String i = "Downloading.... " + downloadedSize
                            + "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int) per
                            + "%)";


        }

        fileOutput.close();




        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/img" + rand+".jpg"); // set your audio path
                file_path= String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(file));





    }  catch (final Exception e) {
        Log.e("////////////////file", String.valueOf(e));
    }
    return file_path;
}
```

And inside my service class when i get the image path in return then i store it inside my sqlite table like this

```
   String img = socketOperator.downloadFile(event_img);
                localstoragehandler.insert(id, msg_user_by, msg_read_by, msg_content, msg_grp_id, ms‌​g_sent_time,type,event_time,event_lat,event_log,event_name,event_address,img);
```

I checked the path with image and id are same.I try this but really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You haven't told us what exactly the problem is. It's your so crashing? Is nothing appearing in the `ImageView`? Without that information it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @Xaver thanks for the reply actually my Image is not loading in the Imageview

Comment: But on a first glance: you said you already have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest. But do you also have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? You know... Since you are trying to read and not write?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android

Comment: @XaverKapeller i added the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission but the problem is not resolve

Comment: @sasikumar thanks for the reference link but it not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You need this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**READ**_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

[@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) has already answered this. Try changing how you get your path. ([Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215606/4180965))

> Why would this happen?

Because the path to external storage has changed over the years, which is why you should have never hard-coded the path in the first place.

> how can I get the path directory in a more "formal and right" way
>   instead of hardcoding the path?

Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

On your test environment, /sdcard is a symlink or hardlink to /storage/sdcard0, as set up by the device manufacturer. However, there is no guarantee that all devices will have such an /sdcard symlink.

---

If that does not help you. This definitely will: [Reading from internal storage.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768380/4180965)

> UPDATE

Please look for all usages of this "/download/img" ...

You are missing a "/" ... Replace it with "/download/img/"

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i am using this  file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/img" + rand+".jpg");    
                    file_path= String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(file)); and this file path i am storing in the Sqlite table

Comment: Can you please add the rest of your code? Where you are specifying "img_db"

Comment: yes you are coreect but when i try this i get the exception E/img_db: file:///storage/sdcard0/download/img15512FILE.jpg------------->
01-25 14:30:38.522 2509-2509/com.myapp.cowite E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/sdcard0/download/img15512FILE.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: look at the log, you are still missing a forward slash at : "download/img/15512FILE.jpg"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101560/discussion-between-tejjd-and-shubhank-gupta).

Comment: problem is not solve actually i am adding the img as prefix for the image