# Accessing SD CARD and doing FILE IO Operations

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard, mkdir

I am trying to create a folder and then after that do some file IO operations!
I am using a sony Xperia Z to test this out!
I know right now I've hardcoded the location but it doesn't let me create folders!

```
  File appPath = new File("/storage/sdcard1/folder");
        if (!appPath.exists()) {
            appPath.mkdirs();
}
```

I am using a targetSdkVersion of 22
And having lollipop on my phone.
I tried

```
appPath.mkDir();
```

as well but all this gives a value of False.
And i have added permissions to manifest

```
<uses-permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I tried many different open source file manager but none are able to create folders, But ES file Manager is able to create folders and do File IO operations!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109307/mkdir-works-while-inside-internal-flash-storage-but-not-sd-card

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs() and do not continue if false but display a toast saying so.

Comment: Lollipop does not allow you to write to a micro sd card.

Comment: @JaredRummler thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode global paths like `/sdcard`, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and related methods instead. Here is a working sample.

```
   public static String getNewFolderPath() {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + File.separator + "folder");
        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdirs();
        return folder.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
For more info check:

- [Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)
- [@CommonsWare Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215606/4848308)
- [@Aleadam Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6049446/4848308)

Hope it helps!

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory gives /storage/emulated/0 which is the internal storage in my phone!
Btw the problem is not about hardcoding, the problem is about i cannot write in SD Card!

Comment: Yes I understand, but `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is for getting SD Card path, I edited my answer with some links that will explain you, your actual problem. Good luck :)

Comment: No. getExternalStorageDirectory() is for getting path to external storage. And in most devices that is not the path to a removable micro sd card.

Comment: @g2o I don't have the problem with getting the SD card path or internal storage path, the point is I'm not able to write to an external SD card even if i hardcode the correct path!