# How to write/read a folder/file in android storage

Tags: android, local-storage, storage, environment

Currently, I'm using below method to create a path in android external storage.

```
public void createPath() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/myFolder/";
    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }
}
```

As far as I understand `getExternalStorageDirectory()` does not exclusively refer to external storage. So this method will create `myFolder` in user preferred storage (which is generally internal storage).

Now I have a question:

What happens if the default storage(user preferred storage) has been set to `SD Card` and it's not readable/writable? What is the best way to handle this situation?

In another word, How can I create this folder safely?(Internal or External doesn't matter ).

Answer (score 0):

create folder in internal storage is safe and No need to access.

```
//Get free Size internal memory
File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
long freeSizeInternalMemoryMB = ((availableBlocks * blockSize) / 1024) / 1024;

//2M available
if (freeSizeInternalMemoryMB > 2) {
    //code for create and copy file
}else{
    //show error for low storage
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but directory should be easily accessible(for user)

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand getExternalStorageDirectory() does not exclusively refer to external storage.

Yes, it does, for what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> So this method will create myFolder in user preferred storage (which is generally internal storage).

No, what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) is something else.

> What happens if the default storage(user preferred storage) has been set to SD Card and it's not readable/writable?

Android itself does not have a concept of "user preferred storage", unless I am misinterpreting your description.

> How can I create this folder safely?

Your code there seems fine.

There is a very small percentage of devices (my guess: ~0.1%) where external storage is on removable media. This was the dominant model for Android 1.x/2.x, but those devices are not used much anymore, and most newer devices have internal and external storage both on on-board flash. If the user ejected the removable media, you will not have access to external storage. There are methods on `Environment` for getting the external storage state. However, you then have no place to write your files where the user can access them. Your choices would be:

- Store the files on internal storage, then migrate them to external storage at a later time, when the media is available again
- Do not store anything, asking the user to please make external storage available again

Comment: In this [Image](http://www.symphonyrecords.ir/storage.jpg), "user preferred/default storage" has been set to **SD Card**, right? now all I'm asking is what happens if this SDCard is not writable? then my folder will not be created, right? Now all I'm asking is what should I do in this situation. half of my application depends on this folder.

Comment: @S.R: ""user preferred/default storage" has been set to SD Card, right?" -- that is not something from standard Android, and I do not know what it means. "now all I'm asking is what happens if this SDCard is not writable?" -- I have not seen an SD card with a hardware read-only switch in a decade or so. I am not aware that Android supports non-writeable SD cards. "then my folder will not be created, right?" -- I doubt that anyone on the planet can answer that. "Now all I'm asking is what should I do in this situation" -- tell the user to fix their device, I guess.