# Create Database on SD Card From File

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sdcard

I'm working with Android and I'm trying to use a database I already have. I'd like to put it on the SD card. I have the database file in my project's assets folder. How can I make it on the SD card or external storage of whatever device the app is installed on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Step1 : Checked accessiblity on sd card
public boolean doesSDCardAccessible(){
    try {
        return(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED));        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }   
    return false;
    }

//Step2 : create directory on SD Card
//APP_DIR : your PackageName 
public void createAndInitAppDir(){
    try {
    if(doesSDCardAccessible()){
    AppDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),APP_DIR+"/");
    if(!AppDir.exists()){
        AppDir.mkdirs();    
    }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

//Step 3 : Create Database on sdcard
//APP_DIR : your PackageName 
//DATABASE_VERSION : give Database Vesrion
//DATABASE_NAME : your Databsename Name
public void initDB()
{
    try {

    //Using SQLiteHelper Class Created Database
    sqliteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(Application.this,AppDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+DATABASE_NAME, 
                                    null, DATABASE_VERSION);    

    //OR use following
    //Creating db here. or db will be created at runtime whenever writable db is opened.

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(AppDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+DATABASE_NAME,                                                     null);*/
    db= sqliteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11281048/1131435), you can find the directory of the SD card in Android 4.0+ by trying both of the following (only one should work per device):

```
new File("/mnt/external_sd/");
```

or

```
new File("/mnt/extSdCard/");
```

On Android <4.0, you can use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

You can create your SQLite database there. Additionally, if you can't find it, you can iterate over all directories in `/mnt/` (note: the sdcard will *always* be accessible via `/mnt/`).

Comment: Can I access it from the SD Card?

Comment: Access what? The database?

Answer (score 0):

The database is like any other flat file.  Just copy it to your SD card.

```
public boolean backup()
{
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = new File("/data/data/com.mydomain.myappname/databases/");

    if (sdcard.canWrite())
    {
    File input = new File(data, DB_NAME);
    File output = new File(sdcard, "android/data/com.mydomain.myappname/databases/");

    if(!output.exists())
    {
        if(output.mkdirs())
        {
            output = new File(sdcard,
            "android/data/com.mydomain.myappname/databases/backup.db");
            output.createNewFile();
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            output = new File(sdcard,
            "android/data/com.mydomain.myappname/databases/backup.db");
            result = true;
        }

        if(input.exists() && result)
        {
            FileInputStream source;
            FileOutputStream destination;

            try
            {
                source = new FileInputStream(input);
                    try
                    {
                        destination = new FileOutputStream(output);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int length;

                        while((length = source.read(buffer)) > 0)
                        {
                            destination.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }

                        source.close();
                        destination.flush();
                        destination.close();
                        result = true;
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       result = false;
                       destination = null;
                   }
               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   result = false;
                   source = null;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               result = false;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           result = false;
       }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: And what, exactly, is not working?  If you don't describe the problem, don't be surprised when you don't get an answer.

Comment: Of course. I'm just having trouble figuring out what's going on myself. For some reason, the DataBaseHelper class I found here: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/  refuses to create the database...even though I was able to create it on other devices. Do I need certain permissions to be able to create the database in the location specified in that code?

Comment: It's actually strange. I can run createDatabase() and openDatabase() just fine, as well as getReadableDatabase(). But then when I try to query it, it claims the columns don't exist...so either the database didn't create properly or it didn't create at all. But...why wouldn't it return an error?

Answer (score 0):

Go throuh this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)

OR try following

```
 InputStream myInput;

        try {

                     AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            myInput =  assetManager.open("mydatabase.db");


            File directory = new File("/sdcard/some_folder");

            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            }

            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory
                    .getPath() + "/DatabaseSample.backup");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();

            myOutput.close();

            myInput.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```