# How do I get multiple storage file paths on Android?

Tags: android, storage

In my phone I have two storages, one of them is SD card and the other is `extsdcard`.

I can get the sdcard path by:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
.toString()
```

How do I get the extsdcard file path?

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: android phone version 4.0.4, not international brand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get the other external sdcard:

```
 File storageDir=   new File("/mnt/external_sd/")
```

OR

```
 File storageDir=   new File("/mnt/extSdCard/")
```

For more details see http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/detect-SD-Card-path-td5710218.html#a5710250  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

So that Like this use a function to get list of all ext cards...

```
public static HashSet<String> getExternalMounts() {
    final HashSet<String> out = new HashSet<String>();
    String reg = "(?i).*vold.*(vfat|ntfs|exfat|fat32|ext3|ext4).*rw.*";
    String s = "";
    try {
        final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount")
                .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        process.waitFor();
        final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
            s = s + new String(buffer);
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // parse output
    final String[] lines = s.split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (!line.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("asec")) {
            if (line.matches(reg)) {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                for (String part : parts) {
                    if (part.startsWith("/"))
                        if (!part.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("vold"))
                            out.add(part);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: how can i get the string (path) by programmaticlly?

Comment: String path=storageDir.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Hardcoding sdcard path is not a good idea, it may be different on different devices

Comment: Maybe yot are not clear with the quastion, the quastion is that: if you have two storage sdcard and extended sdcard yo can get the files in the sd card by  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString() this way, for the other one is there any similar way to get the files?

Comment: Use a function like getExternalMounts()