# Get external sdcard in android phone

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

I got the both the external and internal(phone memory ) `SD` card in listing  in  my application
 but along with that i got some more  folder and i don't want them so how can i limit to external and internal `SD` card only in listing...

i provided the root directory which is    `/storage` and it displays whole the folder...

or can some one tell me how to get external sd card programmaticaly

i have tried the usual way File `file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

given by android but it returned only internal path .

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory(). check the docs and the note under `getExternalStorageDirectory ()`.

Comment: not possible it'll return external path

Comment: The other folders you got should just be USB drives... you should be able to filter them using (file.length() > 0) and/or file.canRead(). Read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0/19831522

Comment: In any case, instead of using the hard-coded path "/storage", use: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getParent()!

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` it returns sd card path but depends on the device

for better under standing check [Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)