# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() return sdcard0 but I have my SD in sdcard1

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I try to write something into SD Card phone memory using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() to get the SD Path, and the result is /storage/sdcard0. But my SD Card is /storage/sdcard1. How to get the real SD Card path?

I can see in "/" that there is a symbolic link called /ext_sd linked to /storage/sdcard1. This symbolic link is in all devices?

Comment: please see [Android: Finding the SD Card Path](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-finding-sd-card-path.html) for getting External sdcard path on Samsung devices

Comment: The basic problem you face is that the handling of additional external storage volumes is device/vendor unique.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this post: [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

```
/**
 * Returns the list of external devices mounted.
 * 
 * @return HashSet<String>.
 */
public static HashSet<String> getExternalMounts() {
    final HashSet<String> out = new HashSet<String>();
    String reg = "(?i).*vold.*(vfat|ntfs|exfat|fat32|ext3|ext4).*rw.*";
    String s = "";
    try {
        final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount")
                .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        process.waitFor();
        final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
            s = s + new String(buffer);
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // parse output
    final String[] lines = s.split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (!line.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("asec")) {
            if (line.matches(reg)) {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                for (String part : parts) {
                    if (part.startsWith("/"))
                        if (!part.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("vold"))
                            out.add(part);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: This is silly - don't launch the mount command as a process, read /proc/mounts as text file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/Save PIP/");
                dir.mkdirs();


                File file = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");


               // Utils.showAlert("Image Saved to SD Card", "PIP Effect", "Ok", FrameActivity.this);

                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                try {

                    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap_final.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

here,You can get your sd card path.I wish it will help you and your solve your problem very soon.