# how can i play videos on android if they are stored in a FOLDER in the sdcard1?

Tags: android, video, android-sdcard

the getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the path to sdcard0. But generally videos and audios are stored in the sdcard1, that too in folders. How can i get the path to these folders ?

Comment: I think you need to refer to :
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13648873/6127411 &&
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695129/6127411

Answer (score 1):

You can try set path like this:

```
...("/sdcard1/folder/file");
```

Comment: But then,the path will be specific to my device only, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Make videoView,

VideoView videoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);        
    videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard1/blonde_secretary.3gp");
    videoView.start();  
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.