# How do I check the type of sdcard's filesystem?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

How to check the type of sdcard's filesystem?

For example, in Windows we can see NTFS, FAT32, exFAT, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to run the *mount* command then do some string processing on the result:

```
    try{
        Process mount = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mount.getInputStream()));
        mount.waitFor();

        String extPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
            for(int i = 0; i < split.length - 1; i++)
            {
                if(split[i].contentEquals(extPath) ||
                    split[i].contains("sdcard") ||
                    split[i].contains("_sd") ||
                    split[i].contains("extSd") ||
                    split[i].contains("_SD"))   // Add wildcards to match against here
                {
                    String strMount = split[i];
                    String strFileSystem = split[i+1];

                    // Add to a list/array of mount points and file systems here...
                    Log.i("SDCard", "mount point: "+ strMount + " file system: " + strFileSystem);
                }
            }
        }           
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
```

Running this on my G Pro gave me the following results:

```
mount point: /mnt/media_rw/external_SD file system: vfat
mount point: /storage/external_SD file system: fuse
```

Some common Android file system types:

- **yaffs/yaffs2** - [Yet Another Flash File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAFFS)
- **ext4** - [Extended File System version 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)
- **fuse** - [File System in User Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)
- **tmpfs** - [Temporary File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs)
- **vfat** - [FAT file system extension](http://www.all-things-android.com/content/understanding-android-file-hierarchy)

Comment: Thanks for your answer before and I will accept it when I was helped. I have the following results: "mount point: /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure file system: tmpfs". But on your result: "mount point: /mnt/media_rw/external_SD file system: vfat" and "mount point: /storage/external_SD file system: fuse". So, what does it mean? What are tmpfs, vfat and fuse?

Comment: I have tested your code for many of my friends' phone (JellyBean). It works on phone memory only (1.4GB), not on their sdcard. I would vote your comment up or vote your answer up if you could help me again. Thanks...

Comment: I have edited the answer to include more strings to match against. The SD card path is different for different phone manufacturers. This question has more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123461/external-sdcard-file-path-for-android You can also match against the result returned from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). Also, check what the path is on your friend's phone and add it to the list.

Comment: @UbuntuForums_Staff_Are_Trolls Java

Answer (score 2):

For custom path, we can use this static method:

```
public static String getFileSystem(File path){
    try{
        Process mount = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mount.getInputStream()));
        mount.waitFor();

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
            for (int i = 0; i < split.length - 1; i++){
                if (!split[i].equals("/") && path.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(split[i]))
                    return split[i + 1];
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        mount.destroy();
    }catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

For example, below code:

```
Log.i("---", "Filesystem = "+ getFileSystem(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
```

will produce this output:

```
I/---: Filesystem = vfat
```