# Permissions not showing while installing apk

Tags: android, permissions, actionscript

I'm making an Android app with ActionScript using FlashBuilder. I need to use The WiFi permission for my app. The application works on desktop with no problems(AIR Desktop project). Now when I tried to make it for Android(Mobile Project), it showed me no errors. I enabled the permissions I needed (Network and wifi) and made the .apk file. However, when I install the .apk file on my Android 6.0.1 device(Note 5) it claims that the app asks for no permissions.
I decided to ask for all the permissions from the adobe website

```
<android> 
<manifestAdditions> 
    <![CDATA[ 
        <manifest> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
        </manifest> 
    ]]> 
</manifestAdditions>
```

It asks for some but not for some. The ones it doesn't ask for are the following

```
<manifest> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
        </manifest>
```

I tried making a new MobileProject with FlashBuilder. I left it as default(blank screen) and asked for the internet permission. It also doesn't ask for the permission. Both apps crash upon lunch immediately.

Now there's a warning on the file containing the permissions, "No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document" but that actually appears on a new project before I even touch anything in it.

Comment: Maybe you are using targetSdk=23? If it's true then you should ask all neccessary permissions when they need. If you don't want waste time to ask permissions just decrease targetSdk version to 22

Answer (score 1):

```
Actually android has new policy to show runTime premission from the marshmallow to you need to implement premission at runtime like this in Activity


  protected void checkPermissionForReadWriteStorage() {

        final int writeExternalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        final int readExternalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (writeExternalStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && readExternalStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        } else {
            boolean requestPermissionRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(BaseActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (requestPermissionRationale) {

                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "Please provide  permission for reading images from gallery.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", BaseActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                BaseActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BaseActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 2:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                    getLocationAndSaveInDatabaseOrEnableGPS();


                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The old way of dealing with permissions(app wise) should still work on Marshmallow(my other apps work). Also when I ask for permissions the "old" way some are asked but some are not.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void verifyStoragePermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(YourActivityName.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        } else {


        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Just change the codes below to the permission you needed to display

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this,
       Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Comment: I'm using ActionScript not JAVA.