# How do i use this method in kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have tried many different ways or solutions and none of them seems to work. I have tried a few specific solutions which returns me a string and a context but i do not know what to do with the `context` even if I set the receiver of the `context` as **null** the app returns an **error**. What I want to do is, to be able to `upload an image file` for that I need the file path, a Uri or a content Uri gives me addresses like this

> Content://something_something/304:
>
> But i need something like this "
>   storage/sdcard/something_something/304.jpg"

how do it get that in `KITKAT`?

This is the code/method that I use for getting the path to the selected user Image.

```
public String getPath(Uri uri)
{
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

hope i provided enough details. Thank you for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION\_GET\_CONTENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0 and attach your log cat snapshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KITKAT does not provide the actual image path for security purpose.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >19){
    InputStream imInputStream =  getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imInputStream);
    String imagePath = saveGalaryImageOnKitkat(bitmap);
}
    ///After use you can delete the bitmap.



    private String saveGalaryImageOnKitkat(Bitmap bitmap){
            try{
                File cacheDir;

                if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                cacheDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                else
                cacheDir=getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                if(!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();

                String filename=java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
                File file = new File(cacheDir, filename);


                file.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return null;

        }
```

Comment: Actually i copy the code from my project temp_path is not required.

Comment: long shot but.... Could you please tell me how can I use this code to upload image to a php server? thank you :)

Comment: I implement this using MultipartEntity https://gist.github.com/Kieranties/2225346