# Get the available space on the all the SD-cards

Tags: android, sd-card

I've found a very good method to get paths to all the sd-cards that device has,not only Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , but also external ones. This method is secrond at [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

So, my question is how can I find out free available space on sd card knowing it's path, for example, "storage/extSdCard" or any other

in other words i need a method :

```
public int getExternalAvailableSpaceInBytes(String sdRootPath) {
//here's this method using this sdRootPath
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
long sdAvailSize = (long)stat.getAvailableBlocksLong() * (long)stat.getBlockSizeLong(); 
}
else{
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
double sdAvailSize = (double)stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (double)stat.getBlockSize();
}

double gigaAvailable = sdAvailSize / 1073741824;    //1073741824 =1GB
```

Comment: I specified that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() returns only internal SD card if 2 exists. I need to know available space by path of Sd-card.

Comment: pass the path of other SD cards which are punted instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`

Comment: [how to get path of external SD Cards](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11281010/3326331)

Comment: how ? something like  StatFs stat = new StatFs(new File(sdRootPath)); where sdRootPath is a String?

Comment: I gave this same link in my question above

Comment: StatFs takes String parameter as an argument so provide the path of your SD cards