# System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") return null on some devices

Tags: android, storage, external

I'm trying to get a List of external storages on android devices and in some devices the instruction `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");` returns `null` although the sd card is mounted in the device (4.1.1).

I'm using the [Dimitriy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871043/2781852/) solution to do this and works fine but in some devices I'm having this problem.

Someone know in what cases `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")` can return `null`?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

In my experiments,
Some old HTC devices will returns null when you call `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")`

I found that the actual microSD path in such devices is be mounted in

```
/storage/sdcard0/ext_sd/

/sdcard2/

/mnt/sdcard/ext_sd/
```

Due to external storage environment variable is defined by phone manufacturers.
We don't have a API to exactly get the microSD path.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution.
try it...

First get All files in list

```
var file=new Java.IO.File("storage/");
var listOfStorages=file.ListFiles();

var isSDPresent=false;
if(listOfStorages[1].Name.Containes("emulated")||listOfStorages[0].Name.Containes("-"))
{
   isSDPresent=true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.