# Using HorizontalScrollView for gallery - no pictures inside

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to use a `horizontalscrollview` with the code from [this site](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html).

The code seems to work fine. I get no Errors, the scrollbar is visible and I can also scroll in it but there are no Pictures inside.

Does somebody know why this can happen?

Comment: Include the code that is causing the error.

Comment: How many pictures did you put in the 'test' directory? How many times myGallery.addView() is called?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is pretty self-explanatory: it cannot find the pictures.

Aside from that: it's a pretty old post, the right way to achieve horizontal scrolling like this is to use [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with `LinearLayoutManager` set to `HORIZONTAL`.

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example for the RecyclerView in form of a gallery? This would be really nice.

Comment: That might help a little: http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any pictures in /test directory on your device's SD card?

edit:

The sample code needs some pictures under /(your app's external storage directory)/test directory on SD card.

```
String targetPath = getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test/";
```

Please note that getExternalStorageDirectory() won't return the root path of the sdcard.
If you want access to the root. Refer: [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

And make sure that a permission is needed. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I've deleted the + "/test". Sorry, I Forgot to mention it. I thought I would get all other Images which are saved on my SD Card.

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: @tyczj I'm sorry for I couldn't add a comment to Tschana's question directly because of lack of my reputation score. To clarify the problem, I firstly asked him a question.

Comment: @Tschana I improved my answer. Please try to place some pictures under the app's external directory. The directory should something like /Android/data/(the app's packagename)/test .