# Check if removable sd-card is on device

Tags: android

I'm developing an app for the specific device. When i get external storage path it gives me the location, that is placed on internal memory. I need to find out if there is any removable sd card found on device(true,false).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

Comment: You are out of luck. Android does not provide a method for that. You should let the user of your app indicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me

```
public static HashSet<String> getExternalMounts() {
    final HashSet<String> out = new HashSet<String>();
    String reg = "(?i).*vold.*(vfat|ntfs|exfat|fat32|ext3|ext4).*rw.*";
    String s = "";
    try { 
        final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount")
                .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        process.waitFor(); 
        final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
            s = s + new String(buffer);
        } 
        is.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    // parse output 
    final String[] lines = s.split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (!line.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("asec")) {
            if (line.matches(reg)) {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                for (String part : parts) {
                    if (part.startsWith("/"))
                        if (!part.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("vold"))
                            out.add(part);
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check external sdcard present or not

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
 if(isSDPresent){

}else{

}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question which was asked.

Comment: You want to check whether external SD card is there or not right?

Comment: This returns the state of the **primary** external storage.  The poster's statement translates to the fact that the primary external storage path on the device they are testing points to an onboard memory, rather than a removable card.

Comment: no, its not what i'm looking for. i need to find info about removable sd card. Sometimes external storage can be the internal memory of device.