# how to get path of external memory card in android

Tags: android, path

I have used

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString)
```

but it gives the path of primary storage.i.e /Storage/emulated/0

I also used

```
new File(System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"))
```

This works well but in some devices of samsung it do not work.

Please help.

Comment: Answers to this questions have given multiple times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

Comment: please first search in SO then ask question