# Get filepath of external SD card

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I am trying to find the pathname of external SD card.

The pathname of my external SD card is in `/storage/A085-60BC`

When i use 
`String SDDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`
, it gives me the path of my internal storage instead.

I have tried various other methods like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648873/8642522) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0/40582634#40582634) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40205116/8642522)

but none of them seem to work. all of them just returns me the same internal memory storage path.

Comment: If getExternalFilesDirs() does not give you that path then you are out of luck You could of course list the directories in /storage to see if there is a directory with such an id pattern ####-####. But why do you need the path? You will not be able to write on it.

Comment: hi @greenapps, I only need to read the files from the sd card `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the directory of my internal storage. I need the external one.

Comment: You already told that. I saw it. I can read. But I said: `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

Comment: @greenapps sorry. i thought you were writing shortform. `getExternalFileDirs()` is not a method of `Environment`.

Comment: Indeed. Very good remark. Why do you want it to be a method of it? Moreover it is NOT getExternalFileDirs()! Please read!