# Storing on internal memory instead of sd card

Tags: android, storage, sd-card

I want to store google map screenshots on my sd card co a wrote this code but I don't know if I misunderstood the term external storage or am I doing something wrong because everything works fine but screenshots are saved in my internal phone memory instead of sd card

```
 public void snapshot(View view) {
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }

    if(mExternalStorageWriteable){
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/100MEDIA/");
        dir.mkdirs();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        final File file = new File(dir, "MapScreen"+timeStamp+".png");

        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                bitmap = snapshot;
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        mMap.snapshot(callback);
    }
}
```

I'm using Htc One M8s

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Check out the answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

Comment: Thanks but these didn't help. I can't get path to my sdcard I think somehow it's wirtualy mounted and can't get access, evan if I get path /sdcard from  System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") it saves the image to internal phone memory and not the actual sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

External storage is any storage that world-readable, not necessarily an SD card (or other removable device). While internal storage is storage that is, by default, private to the application.

To specify *removable* external storage is much more complicated because many device manufactures use different directory structures. Try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871043/5115932).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it did't work for me. I don't know why but System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") retrives the path  /sdcard but when I save to this path the files always get saved to the phone memory and not the actual sdcard when I som file manager appp it showed there math /storage for the sd card but even if I enered this path the app woudlnt save on sd card(in this case it didn't save anywhere)