# How to read data from removable SD card in the android file system

Tags: android

I've recently coded a music player which retrieves mp3 files from the phone external storage. The code is as follows:

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
```

Besides this snippet, I want my program to read some songs from the removable SDcard, which I tend to search a lot and did not find a relevant source. How do I access files on the removable SD card. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Thanks in advance :)`. :-(.

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0

Comment: @skbrhmn It helped! thanks.