# I want to get the size of all Video list from external and internal storage?

Tags: android, size

I build an app in which we can delete the duplicate file from external and internal storage. I am able to get all images, videos, songs, and files from phone and external storage. But now I want the size of each image which I get from list of storage.

MainActivity

```
    package com.deitel.duplicatefileremoverapp.VideoContent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.deitel.duplicatefileremoverapp.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VideoMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private VideoRecyclerViewAdapter videoRecyclerViewAdapter;
    File video_storage;
    File video_size;
    String[] allpath;
    String[] allpathsize;
    ArrayList<Long> videomodelclassArrayList=new ArrayList<Long>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.video_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        videoRecyclerViewAdapter = new VideoRecyclerViewAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(videoRecyclerViewAdapter);
        videoRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //Load video data here
        allpath = VideoStorageUtil.getStorageDirectories(this);
        for (String path : allpath) {
            video_storage = new File(path);
            VideoMethod.load_Directory_files(video_storage);
        }
    }
}
```

VideoMethod.class

```
    package com.deitel.duplicatefileremoverapp.VideoContent;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

public class VideoMethod {
    public static void load_Directory_files(File file) {
        File[] filelist = file.listFiles();
        if (filelist != null && filelist.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
                if (filelist[i].isDirectory()) {
                    load_Directory_files(filelist[i]);
                } else {
                    String name = filelist[i].getName().toLowerCase();
                    long size = filelist[i].length()/1024;
                    Log.d(TAG, "load_Directory_files:"+size);
                    for (String extension : VideoConstant.videoextention) {
                        // Check the type of file
                        if (name.endsWith(extension)) {
                            VideoConstant.allmedialist.add(filelist[i]);
                            //when we found file
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VideoRecyclerAdapter.Class

```
    package com.deitel.duplicatefileremoverapp.VideoContent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.deitel.duplicatefileremoverapp.R;

import java.io.File;

public class VideoRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    // Constructore
    VideoRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_file_list, parent, false);
        return new FileLayoutHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((FileLayoutHolder) holder).title.setText(VideoConstant.allmedialist.get(position).getName());       
**Line No.39**(FileLayoutHolder) holder).size.setText(VideoConstant.allmedialist.get(position).length);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(VideoConstant.allmedialist.get(position));
        Glide.with(context).load(uri).thumbnail(0.1f).into(((FileLayoutHolder) holder).thumbnail);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return VideoConstant.allmedialist.size();
    }

    class FileLayoutHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;
        TextView size;

        public FileLayoutHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_name);
            size = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_size);
        }
    }
}
```

VideoStorageUtil.Class

```
    package com.deitel.duplicatefileremoverapp.VideoContent;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Helper class for getting all storages directories in an Android device
 * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/40582634/3940133">Solution of this problem</a>
 * Consider to use
 * <a href="https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider">StorageAccessFramework(SAF)</>
 * if your min SDK version is 19 and your requirement is just for browse and open documents, images, and other files
 *
 * @author Dmitriy Lozenko, HendraWD
 */
public class VideoStorageUtil {

    // Primary physical SD-CARD (not emulated)
    private static final String EXTERNAL_STORAGE = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");

    // All Secondary SD-CARDs (all exclude primary) separated by File.pathSeparator, i.e: ":", ";"
    private static final String SECONDARY_STORAGES = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");

    // Primary emulated SD-CARD
    private static final String EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET = System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET");

    // PhysicalPaths based on phone model
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    @SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
    private static final String[] KNOWN_PHYSICAL_PATHS = new String[]{
            "/storage/sdcard0",
            "/storage/sdcard1",                 //Motorola Xoom
            "/storage/extsdcard",               //Samsung SGS3
            "/storage/sdcard0/external_sdcard", //User request
            "/mnt/extsdcard",
            "/mnt/sdcard/external_sd",          //Samsung galaxy family
            "/mnt/sdcard/ext_sd",
            "/mnt/external_sd",
            "/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1",            //4.4.2 on CyanogenMod S3
            "/removable/microsd",               //Asus transformer prime
            "/mnt/emmc",
            "/storage/external_SD",             //LG
            "/storage/ext_sd",                  //HTC One Max
            "/storage/removable/sdcard1",       //Sony Xperia Z1
            "/data/sdext",
            "/data/sdext2",
            "/data/sdext3",
            "/data/sdext4",
            "/sdcard1",                         //Sony Xperia Z
            "/sdcard2",                         //HTC One M8s
            "/storage/microsd"                  //ASUS ZenFone 2
    };

    public static String[] getStorageDirectories(Context context) {
        // Final set of paths
        final Set<String> availableDirectoriesSet = new HashSet<>();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET)) {
            // Device has an emulated storage
            availableDirectoriesSet.add(getEmulatedStorageTarget());
        } else {
            // Device doesn't have an emulated storage
            availableDirectoriesSet.addAll(getExternalStorage(context));
        }

        // Add all secondary storages
        Collections.addAll(availableDirectoriesSet, getAllSecondaryStorages());

        String[] storagesArray = new String[availableDirectoriesSet.size()];
        return availableDirectoriesSet.toArray(storagesArray);
    }

    private static Set<String> getExternalStorage(Context context) {
        final Set<String> availableDirectoriesSet = new HashSet<>();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Solution of empty raw emulated storage for android version >= marshmallow
            // because the EXTERNAL_STORAGE become something like: "/Storage/A5F9-15F4",
            // so we can't access it directly
            File[] files = getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file != null) {
                    String applicationSpecificAbsolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    String rootPath = applicationSpecificAbsolutePath.substring(
                            0,
                            applicationSpecificAbsolutePath.indexOf("Android/data")
                    );
                    availableDirectoriesSet.add(rootPath);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                availableDirectoriesSet.addAll(getAvailablePhysicalPaths());
            } else {
                // Device has physical external storage; use plain paths.
                availableDirectoriesSet.add(EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }
        return availableDirectoriesSet;
    }

    private static String getEmulatedStorageTarget() {
        String rawStorageId = "";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            // External storage paths should have storageId in the last segment
            // i.e: "/storage/emulated/storageId" where storageId is 0, 1, 2, ...
            final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            final String[] folders = path.split(File.separator);
            final String lastSegment = folders[folders.length - 1];
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lastSegment) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(lastSegment)) {
                rawStorageId = lastSegment;
            }
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rawStorageId)) {
            return EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET;
        } else {
            return EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET + File.separator + rawStorageId;
        }
    }

    private static String[] getAllSecondaryStorages() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(SECONDARY_STORAGES)) {
            // All Secondary SD-CARDs split into array
            return SECONDARY_STORAGES.split(File.pathSeparator);
        }
        return new String[0];
    }
    private static List<String> getAvailablePhysicalPaths() {
        List<String> availablePhysicalPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String physicalPath : KNOWN_PHYSICAL_PATHS) {
            File file = new File(physicalPath);
            if (file.exists()) {
                availablePhysicalPaths.add(physicalPath);
            }
        }
        return availablePhysicalPaths;
    }
    private static File[] getExternalFilesDirs(Context context, String type) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            return context.getExternalFilesDirs(type);
        } else {
            return new File[]{context.getExternalFilesDir(type)};
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
     Process: com.deitel.duplicatefileremoverapp, PID: 24470
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x30c9fd
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:336)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4465)
        at com.deitel.duplicatefileremoverapp.VideoContent.VideoRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(VideoRecyclerViewAdapter.java:39)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
```

Comment: Use File.length   ?

Comment: yes i get the file of video storage from external and internal storage

Comment: but now i want the size of list of videos which i get from external and internal storage

Comment: Use File.length ? –

Comment: i use (long size = filelist[i].length()/1024;)..it is working but unable to show in textview in recyclerview.it give me error onBindviewholder..... Line.No39

Comment: Well that is a completely different problem. And which code is on line 39?

Comment: **Line No.39**(FileLayoutHolder) holder).size.setText(VideoConstant.allmedialist.get(position).length);

Comment: And if you use as test `((FileLayoutHolder) holder).size.setText("xxxxx");` then what happens?

Comment: Please post more logcat lines. (in your post. not in a comment). We still dont know the error now.

Comment: i update the post with error body please check out that

Comment: Please do the test i suggested.