# How to get the path from any USB connected?

Tags: android, path, usb

I´m developing an app which can read a txt file (electroUser.txt) from an USB i connect, but i do not know how to get the path.

I´m using the path i got from another app.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        //File file = new File("/storage/usb_storage/","electroUser.txt");

        File file = new File("/storage/2EB5-0400/","electroUser.txt");

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            electroUser=br.readLine();

            br.close();

            if(electroUser.equals("Jg123jhg0976")) 

                text.setText("José Molina");

        } catch (Throwable e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

});
```

I want to get the path from any USB i connect. I know the way i´m doing it is not the best.

Comment: Can you check below path, It will be help full to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262830/how-to-find-the-path-of-usb-which-is-mounted-to-android