# Getting sd card directory in Android device

Tags: android, linux

Below is the code written for retrieving the sd card directory.
I have been using execution of command and changed into reading the /proc/mounts.
My Question is whether it is the right code ?

Not an expert on Linux OS. Will the /proc/mounts path be same for all the devices ?
I think this code will be also free of any command injection possiblities.

```
// Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount").start();
        // process.waitFor();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/mounts"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Output the line of output from the mount command
            logger.debug("   {}", line);

            if (line.startsWith("/dev/block/vold/")) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
                if (tokens.length >= 3 && (tokens[2].equals("vfat") || tokens[2].equals("exfat"))) {
                    String path = tokens[1];
                    File file = new File(path);
                    if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
                        logger.debug("Detected SD card at {}", file.getPath());

                        if (!file.canWrite()) {
                            logger.warn("The SD card path {} is reporting that it is not writable", file.getPath());
                        }

                        return path;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: y so much to do to get android sdcard path

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Comment: As far as i know using this API will not be correct since different manufcatures will consider the external storage differently.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340332/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-mounted-external-storage-of-android-device/19982338#19982338

Answer (score 4):

On Android you can get the sd card's directory on any device through

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: As far as i know using this API will not be correct since different manufcatures will consider the external storage differently.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340332/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-mounted-external-storage-of-android-device/19982338#19982338

Comment: Actually it's the api that is meant to specifically avoid that problem

Comment: Also check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0. Envrionment.getExternalStorageDirectory() does not work in all the situations

Comment: It should still give a directory you can write into... I always use it and never had a problem. Well, ignore my answer I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Please use

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` to get the path to SD card.

Also, use `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` against attribute `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED` etc, to check if the SD card is Readable, Mounted etc. :)

Comment: As far as i know using this API will not be correct since different manufcatures will consider the external storage differently.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340332/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-mounted-external-storage-of-android-device/19982338#19982338

Comment: I am really not sure about that. However google docs says that this is the method to access it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29

Comment: Also check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0. Envrionment.getExternalStorageDirectory() does not work in all the situations