# Incomplete Android documentation for Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() method

Tags: android

Reference: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

The paragraph addressing devices with multiple "external" storage directories has a hanging sentence explaining what to do about secondary storage:

"In devices with multiple "external" storage directories, this directory represents the "primary" external storage that the user will interact with. Access to secondary storage is available through"

What should come after the "through?"

An issue for this is already open [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=67040) but nobody seems to care.

If anyone knows what are the methods to access the secondary storage, please answer here.

Thx.

Comment: There is a similar topic being discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340332/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-mounted-external-storage-of-android-device/

Answer (score 0):

From the current doc:

> Access to secondary storage is available through `getExternalFilesDirs(String)`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()`.