# scan all media from both internal and External storage

Tags: java, android

Please tell me the idea.

**How to scan all media from Internal as well as External Storage.**

I created a App which only scan data from my internal storage but not all the phone. Please give any idea

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us part of your code which is 'scanning' your internal storage?

Comment: final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

Comment: So it seems like `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns internal storage directory instead. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location/5695129#5695129). In short, there is no straightforward way of doing this, because there is no standard between different manufacturers. People come up with workarounds however. [Another relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340332/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-mounted-external-storage-of-android-device). Sorry there's no simple answer.