# Get all storages and devices with their names android

Tags: android, usb, android-sdcard, mount

I already found out how to get all storages with either of these answers: [with proc/mounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982338/5288316) and [with mount command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648873/5288316), but now I want to put a name on the paths returned. I have no problem with Internal Storage, however these methods can't distinguish between a SD card and a USB stick. If it sees two drives connected how can I be sure which one is the SD Card and which is the USB, or are they two SD Cards? Or two USB drives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found part of the solution, however I won't get any farther because it's getting complicated and this is not the main feature of my app anyway.

```
public static class Storage extends File {

    public static final int INTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    public static final int SD_CARD = 2;
    public static final int USB_DRIVE = 3;

    public String name;
    public int type;

    public Storage(String path, String name, int type) {
        super(path);
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Storage> getStorages(Context context) {
    ArrayList<Storage> storages = new ArrayList<>();

    // Internal storage
    storages.add(new Storage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),
            "Internal Storage", Storage.INTERNAL_STORAGE));

    // SD Cards
    ArrayList<File> extStorages = new ArrayList<>();
    extStorages.addAll(Arrays.asList(context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)));
    extStorages.remove(0); // Remove internal storage
    String secondaryStoragePath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    for (int i = 0; i < extStorages.size(); i++) {
        String path = extStorages.get(i).getPath().split("/Android")[0];
        if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(extStorages.get(i)) || secondaryStoragePath != null && secondaryStoragePath.contains(path)) {
            String name = "SD Card" + (i == 0 ? "" : " " + String.valueOf(i+1));
            storages.add(new Storage(path, name, Storage.SD_CARD));
        }
    }

    // USB Drives
    ArrayList<String> drives = new ArrayList<>();
    String reg = "(?i).*vold.*(vfat|ntfs|exfat|fat32|ext3|ext4).*rw.*";
    String s = "";
    try {
        final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount")
                .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        process.waitFor();
        final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
            s += new String(buffer);
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String[] lines = s.split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (!line.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("asec") && line.matches(reg)) {
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            for (String path : parts) {
                if (path.startsWith(File.separator) && !path.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("vold")) {
                    drives.add(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove SD Cards from found drives (already found)
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Storage st : storages) {
        String[] parts = st.getPath().split(File.separator);
        ids.add(parts[parts.length-1]);
    }
    for (int i = drives.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String[] parts = drives.get(i).split(File.separator);
        String id = parts[parts.length-1];
        if (ids.contains(id)) drives.remove(i);
    }

    // Get USB Drive name
    UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    Collection<UsbDevice> dList = usbManager.getDeviceList().values();
    ArrayList<UsbDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    deviceList.addAll(dList);
    for (int i = 0; i < deviceList.size(); i++) {
        storages.add(new Storage(drives.get(i), deviceList.get(i).getProductName(), Storage.USB_DRIVE));
    }

    return storages;
}
```

- Find internal storage
- Find all SD Cards
- Find all external drives, then remove SD Cards from them, because they were already found. The point of this is to separate SD Cards from USB devices.

I didn't test this with any other device than mine, it won't likely work for every device. Also it is possible that keyboards or mouses counts as connected devices and that will screw up the whole thing.

Comment: well solution at all.

Comment: Use this code with caution! The last for loop is very critical. The code makes a lot of assumptions on the hardware. E.g. it doesn't work on my development board where Wifi adapter and touch sensor are connected using USB as well.

Comment: @OneWorld Yes honestly don't use it at all. A better starting point would be looking how open source file manager do it, like [Amaze File Manager](https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager) or [Simple File Manager](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-File-Manager).