# Accessing names of various cards connected to card reader

Tags: android, usb

I have a card reader connected to an Android device. My UsbDeviceConnection is getting the name and serial of the Card reader. But I want to know how to get the names of each card connected to the card reader when multiple cards are connected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719986/get-all-storages-and-devices-with-their-names-android

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Niza I got the details of the Card reader. and I can access each card with their LUN and perform read/writes using BOT Protocol. I want to know how to access each card's name and serial number.