# How to manage external storage independently of the phone

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have phone (B15 CAT) with a sd card slot. When i insert a sdcard in this phone and asking for the external storage directory with :

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

it always return an space on sdcard0 which is the internal memory. This memory is too small for my need.
By listing /mnt i found a mount point named /sdcard2 which is the "real" scard.
Unfortunately sdcard2 doesn't seems to be a standard and some other brand will use some other name...

Knowing that getExternalStorageDirectory() seems working as expected on phone with no sdcard slot , like nexus 4, **how should i handle external storage to be sure to write on the sdcard (big space available) and not on internal memory ?**

I have tried something like this :

```
File mnt = new File("/mnt");
File[] liste = mnt.listFiles();
boolean hassd2 = false;

for(File mount : liste) {
    if(folder.getName().equals("sdcard2") {
        hassd2 = true;
        break;
    }
}

String path = "";
if(hassd2) {
    path = "/sdcard2/my/folder/"
} else {
    File p = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/my/folder/");
    path = p.toString();
}
```

It's working but only with this specific phone and others one with no sdcard slot ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the problem with the build in functions of Android in case of multiple 'external' storages mounted. I parsed the mounted directories directly from the f_stab file.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450650/how-to-list-additional-external-storage-folders-mount-points/15131810#15131810) should give you the code you needed.

After having the mount points you could try to calculate the available space in order to decide if it is enough for your operation.