# Get a list of external storage in Android 4.3

Tags: android, root, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I've been scanning /etc/vold.fstab to get a list of external storage. It works fine until Android 4.3 that Google removed the file. I know that a unified /fstab.* file is now used but which is inaccessible without root.

So in Android 4.3, what should I do to get a list of external storage?

My code looks something like this. Now it includes both non-removable internal and removable external storage.

```
File voldFile = new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab");

fr = new FileReader(voldFile);
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("dev_mount")) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
        File mountPoint = new File(tokens[2]);
        if (mountPoint.isDirectory() && mountPoint.canRead())
            list.add(tokens[2]);
    }
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: about the listing, is your method used to get both the non-removable , external storage , and the real one (that is usually an sd card) ? if so, can you please show how you do it on earlier versions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15131810/596555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up scanning /proc/mounts output for currently mounted storage. Code similar to below.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    File voldFile = new File("/proc/mounts");

    fr = new FileReader(voldFile);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, line);
        if (line.startsWith("/")) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            if ("vfat".equals(tokens[2])) {
                File mountPoint = new File(tokens[1]);
                if (!tokens[1].equals(defaultMount))
                    if (mountPoint.isDirectory() && mountPoint.canRead())
                        list.add(tokens[1]);
            }
        }
        line = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is defaultMount Here?

Comment: defaultMount is the value returned by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

Comment: This gives just 'local' mounted storage.  It will not give you mounted storage from say an SD card.