# I get wrong directory when usin getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android, path, save, record

I'm writing an app that records sound using MediaRecorder. To get a directory where the recorded file should be saved I do this:

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/record.3gp";
```

And then:

```
mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
```

The audio records fine and I have the file saved but in the wrong place. The file is saved in my internal storage (I'm using GT-I9300). Why is that? How can I get the correct path for any external storage in any device? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this may be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a memory card in your device?
Device that come with a large internal memory, like yours (16GB), will if, if a memory card is not present, return the internal memory location.

If not I assuming the card is not the primary external storage.
Maybe this can be of help? [How to list additional external storage folders (mount points)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450650/how-to-list-additional-external-storage-folders-mount-points)

Comment: Yes, I inserted 4 GB SD card specially for testing my app.

Comment: Added a link to a similar question, other than that I am not sure, if the SD Card is not considered to be the primary external storage, it will not be returned :s